# how to override csproj content files copying behavior

Tags: .net, msbuild, csproj

I have project A which depends on B. B contains content defined in csproj as

```
<Content Include="settings\file" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always"/>
```

I need to exclude this file from copying to output and publishing when `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` are applied to project A. Can it be achieved?

I've tried different solutions and none has worked. For instance, adding lines like these to `A.csproj` still leads to copying `settings\file` to A output and publish directories.

```
<Content Remove="settings\file" CopyToOutputDirectory="Never" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never"/>
<Content Remove="..\B\settings\file" CopyToOutputDirectory="Never" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never"/>
```

I also tried using `Update` instead of `Remove` but still no use.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the output copied and published in most scenarios unless referenced by a specific project, I suggest using a custom propertiy for that:

```
<Content Include="settings\file" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"
  Condition="'$(IncludeSettingsFileOutput)' != 'False' />
```

and then reference it from A.csproj:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\B\B.csproj" AdditionalProperties="IncludeSettingsFileOutput=False" />
```

(Do note that I used `PreserveNewest` instead of `Always` to enable project system level up-to-date checks - `Always` is really only needed if your program modifies the content in the output directory and you need to overwrite it on every build regardless if the files changed in the project or not and your project will never be considered "up to date" by VS)